# Is it possible to have zend modules and non-zend side by side

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

We have a php based website we want to gradually migrate to zend framework. I imagined we could have three new components developed on the framework and the rest as they are in the old website.

Is it possible to achieve this only through sharing the session and filtering the http requests? In other words, if I request http://website.com?component=old_component then we serve the old website, and if http://website.com?component=new_zend_component we serve the framework? in each case the user's rights would be verified through the corresponding session information.

Or is it required the old website be under the framework's controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve this using apache/nginx/your server's rewrite rules. But if you have complex url structure it could be tricky.

If you'll go with controller maybe it is good idea to have just one default route for "old_components" and specific routes for new ones. But this is not really good approach since you'll be loading ZF + your old project, this will take longer to process than just using web servers rewrite rules.

Comment: Thank you Maksym, actually if it is possible I would load either old site or framework pages, but not together. Do you still think the same? Thank you

Comment: Then try rewrite rules, it should work. Do you need help with them?

Comment: Thank you Maksym, no no help needed. I just wanted to know I could go the way I envisioned it before I jump to the task. :) Bests